# Taking the weighted mean of parts of a list using another list

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I have three lists:

```
data = {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0};
time = {1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4};
weight = {0.5,0.5,0.5,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8};
```

`data` represents a data points that were recorded at the instance given by the vector `time`. Each recording has a specific weight attached to it, given in the `weight` vector.

#### The question

I would like to calculate for every time step.

`{1,1,1,1 ...}` -> is one time step (multiple recordings),

`{...,4,4,4,4}` -> is another time step

...the weighted mean of the data.

How can I do it with Mathematica? I need to have a scalable solution, since I will incorporate multiple data.

I was thinking about using:

`WeightedData[data, weight]` to calculate the weighted data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way. There will be many more!

```
{#[[1, 1]], Mean[WeightedData[#[[;; , 2]], #[[;; , 3]]]]} & /@ GatherBy[Transpose[{time, data, weight}], First]
```

Another:

```
GroupBy[{time, data, weight}\[Transpose], First -> Rest, Mean@*Apply[WeightedData]@*Transpose]
```

Comment: Really nice use of GroupBy +1 !!

Answer (score 4):

```
Merge[Mean@*Apply[WeightedData]@*Transpose]@ Thread[time -> {data, weight}\[Transpose]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
GroupBy[Transpose[{time, weight, data * weight}], First, 
(Total[#[[;; , -1]]]/Total[#[[;; , 2]]]) &]
```

> <|1 -> 0.277778, 4 -> 0.461538|>

Answer (score 1):

Using `Dataset`:

```
ds = Transpose@Dataset@AssociationMap[Symbol, {"data", "time", "weight"}]

ds[GroupBy["time"], Mean@WeightedData[#[[All, "data"]], #[[All, "weight"]]] &]

(*OR*)

ds[GroupBy["time"], Transpose][All, Mean@WeightedData[#data, #weight] &]
```

[image]

Another way, without `Transpose`:

```
ds = Dataset@AssociationMap[Symbol, {"data", "time", "weight"}];
ds["time", PositionIndex][All, ds[All, #][Mean@WeightedData[#data, #weight] &] &]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MapThread[#1 -> Mean@*Apply[WeightedData]@Transpose[#2] &, {Union @@ #1, 
Partition[{data, weight}\[Transpose], Sequence @@ Map[Length]@#]}] &@GatherBy[time]

(* {1 -> 0.277778, 4 -> 0.461538} *)
```

Comment: @DoHe you can upvote answers you find useful in order to express your appreciation. No need to thank everyone around :) Please take a [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @Kuba, okay thanks for the note !